# Create and write on .txt file using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a .txt file using c# and write on it although my code runs without any errors the file doesn't exist after i run it

```
string path = @"C:\Users\stra\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp2\file.txt";

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                //writes to file
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path,"Text to add to the file\n");
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the file.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Text to add to the file\n");
                }

            }
            // Open the stream and read it back.
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Check your bin folder. It may be placed inside that.

Comment: When using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()` there's no need for a `FileStream`. The `using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))` creates and locks the file, so the subsequent call to `WriteAllText()` will fail. Simply get rid of the `FileStream`.

Comment: Are you getting the "Text to add to the file" value written out to the console when reading it?

Comment: Have you tried a more "compliant" path - without spaces?  Try c:\temp\file.txt as a start.

Comment: Are you guys in the same class or something? You have the same exact bug as in the marked duplicate, posted just yesterday. It's illegal to write to the same file you just opened using `File.Create()` until you have closed that stream. I doubt it's true your code _"runs without errors"_. You just don't notice the error.

Comment: @ChrisCruz yes but if i close the program and then run it again wanting to write something else to the file it overwrites on it.Any suggestions on how to change that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem that I see with the above code is that when you create the file, you have an open filestream to it which prevents any other processes from accessing the file. When you then attempt to call System.IO.File.WriteAllText the code throws an IOException as the file is locked. This is expected according to the [documentation for File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.

To resolve this I would change the below code:

```
// Create the file.
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Text to add to the file\n");
}
```

To either not use the filestream, so just use the File class:

```
// Create the file.
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Text to add to the file\n");
```

Or if you want to use a filestream, write to it with the FileStream Write method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
   // Create the file.
   using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
   {
      char[] value = "Text to add to the file\n".ToCharArray();
      fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), 0, value.Length);
   }
```

With either of these modifications, the above code works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder I have updated my answer to give examples. I've also added more detail that hopefully clarifies that I'm not missing the problem - I did run the code and experience an issue which my suggestions resolve.